# Specializing function template for reference types

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, template-specialization, reference-type

Why is the output of this [code](http://www.ideone.com/IlirG) :

```
#include <iostream>  
template<typename T> void f(T param) 
{ 
   std::cout << "General" << std::endl ; 
} 
template<> void f(int& param) 
{ 
   std::cout << "int&" << std::endl ; 
}  

int main() 
{   
  float x ;  f (x) ;   
  int y ; f (y) ;   
  int& z = y ; f (z) ; 
}
```

is

> General
>   General
>   General

The third one is surprizing because the function was specialized exactly for `int&`

Edit : I know that overloading might be a proper solution. I just want to learn the logic behind it.

Comment: Maybe because const int& is preferred to int&?

Comment: @Septagram: const int& ?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but if you change the template to accept a `T &`, then both `f(y)` and `f(z)` call the `int &` version.

Comment: @Daniel Gallagher: Then you have a compiler error with `f(2);`. Also the output of`f(y)` is `int&`.

Comment: The best way is to use an overload  `void f(int& param)`  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: You can switch to `const T &` and `const int &` to make `f(2)` work, but yes, `f(y)`, `f(z)`, and `f(2)` will all call the `const int &` version.

Comment: @Johnsyweb : http://www.ideone.com/lRck6

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile.  Correct function template spec looks like: `template < > void f<int&>(int& blah)...`

Comment: @Noah Roberts: It was an answer to a deleted comment;

Comment: @sad_man - huh?  I wasn't referring to your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type of both the expression `y` and the expression `z` is `int`. A reference appearing in an expression won't keep reference type. Instead, the type of the expression will be the referenced type, with the expression being an lvalue.

So in both cases, `T` is deduced to `int`, and thus the explicit specialization is not used at all.

What's important to note (other than that you should really use overloading, as another guy said), is that you have a non-reference function parameter in your template. Before any deduction of `T` against the argument type is done, the argument type will be converted from arrays to a pointer to their first element (for functions, arguments will be converted to function pointers). So a function template with a non-reference function parameter doesn't allow for accurate deduction anyway.

Comment: +1 (and thanks for spotting the mistake in my own answer while I am at it)

Comment: About your second sentence : where does this rule come from ? I trust you, but do you have any source explaining this point ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A reference is just an alias, not a type.  So when you call f(z), it matches the first version with T=int, which is a better option that T=int&.  If you change T to T&, then both int and int& arguments will call the second version.

Comment: If I change T to T&, I have compiler error when `f(2)` or `f("text")`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not answer but, IMHO you can try this, with a trait like approach in a struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct value_traits
{
    static void print(){std::cout << "General" << std::endl ;} 
};

template<>
struct value_traits<const long>
{
    static void print(){std::cout << "const long" << std::endl ;} 
};

template<>
struct value_traits<std::vector<unsigned char> >
{
    static void print(){std::cout << "std::vector<unsigned char>" << std::endl ; }
};

template<>
struct value_traits<const int>
{
       static void print(){std::cout << "const int" << std::endl ;} 
};
```