# Wrapping std::cout in a function call

Tags: c++

I have a lot of couts and so I would like to be able to make a function that can take just three arguments. The function would print them out to the screen just as cout does like this:

```
print( 5, " is a ", "number" );

// should do the same thing as

cout << 5 << " is a " << "number" << endl;
```

I'm not asking anyone to do it. I'm just looking for a way to be able to. But if you can provide the code that would be good as well. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks.

Comment: 1) What have you tried, 2) how would the function be better thatn `cout << ...`, and 3) have you heard of templates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2>
void print(T0 const& t0, T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2)
{
    std::cout << t0 << t1 << t2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Scott Meyers (in Effective C++) recommends that you use pass by const ref for all types, except for builtin types (char, int, double, etc.), for iterators and for function objects (classes deriving from std::*_function).

Comment: What does the `const& t0` do? Please explain in layman terms as I am not quite proficient in c++.

Comment: @0A0D:  That is true, and given the specific example in the original question, one might prefer to pass by value (one might also prefer not to use a template, depending on what the types of the arguments are).  In a template, though, the norm is to accept by `const&` instead of by value, to handle the "worst case."

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Do you have a reference on the norm? I am interested in reading more.

Comment: @David:  It is a const-qualified reference.  For more, I would recommend [a good introductory C++ text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @0A0D:  Off the top of my head, I can't think of an "official" reference.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876913/template-pass-by-value-or-const-reference-or) for a few reasons why `const&` (or `&&` in C++11) is usually preferable.

Comment: Nitpick: your function's arguments go from t0 to t2, yet you output to `cout` variables from t1 to t3.

Comment: @eq-:  Thanks, fixed.  (I'm not very good at counting; I usually make my computer count things for me.)

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to be able to make a function that can take just three arguments

Are you sure?  C++11 affords us much more power than that.

```
void print()
{
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(const T & val, Args&&... args)
{
    std::cout << val;
    print(args...);
}
```

Comment: I said I wanted just three arguments because I was afraid the examples given to me depicting functions that can take unlimited arguments would be too complex for me to grasp. Is this code supposed to work as-is? I ran it and it gave me the error: `expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token'`

Comment: @David: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using the built-in compiler from CodeBlocks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I got a warning that said `variadic templates only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x` I don't know what this means.

Comment: @David: That's probably GCC, though I don't know which version.  If you can figure out how to add the option `"-std=c++0x"` to the command line, then do that.  If you have no idea what I'm talking about, then go on to the codeblocks forums, [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/), and see if they can help you. Ask them, "How do I set up codeblocks to work with C++11?", they should be able to help you. (**Edit**) By your other comment, I see you definitely have a GCC version that supports the option.  You just need to figure out how to add it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with templates:

```
template<typename T, typename S, typename U>
print(T x, S y, U z)
{
    std::cout << x << y << z;
}
```

EDIT: If you're expecting to pass complex types (not just `int` or `char *`) you should follow James' answer and use `const` references.

Answer (score 2):

you could use macros... (if you want to do that, can be ugly sometimes)

```
#define PRINT(x,y,z) cout << (x) << (y) << (z) << endl;
```

Comment: I like your answer because you don't have to use templates. :)

Comment: It's more of a readability advantage in my opinion. And besides, you can pass various types into `print`.

Comment: If you have to write that really often, it is much more convenient to use macros than templates.

Comment: What's more convenient about it?

Comment: print<string,string,int>("a", "b", 3) vs. print("a", "b", 3)

Comment: @Misch: Or, with template type deduction, `print("a","b",3)` vs. `print("a","b",3)`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: never heard about type deduction. But in that case, the macro seems not being more convenient any more...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to simplify the specific task of printing three items, you can do it using a #define macro:

```
#define print(A,B,C) cout << (A) << (B) << (C) << endl
```

If you prefer a function-call syntax, consider using C-style output instead: `printf` is a "first-class member" of the C++ standard library, there is no reason to shy away from it when it makes sense in your specific application:

```
printf("%d %s %s\n", 5, "is a", "number");
```

The advantage of `printf` approach is that it is not limited to any specific number of arguments.

Comment: `print(a++, "is a", a++);` is worse than unspecified, it is undefined, and it would be even if `print` was a function instead of a macro.  But that's not the function/macro's fault, it is the fault of the caller.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are correct on that, the reference is of no interest as far as this question is concerned. I edited the answer to remove it, thanks!