# How to specialize classes for all reference types C++03

Tags: c++, template-specialization, c++03

Please notice C++03 is what I really need, but for knowledge sake, I would like to see some more pretty implementations in C++11 as well.

I need a template class

```
template <typename T>
class A {
private:
    T m_member;

public:
    A(T _member);    
    //... MORE STUFF
    void foo(T param);
};
```

I need:

### 1) If A is compiled with a value type (including pointers, which by themselves are passed by value):

Then I need A to look like this (exactly like above)

```
class A {
private:
    T m_member;

public:
    A(T _member);    
    //... MORE STUFF
    void foo(T param);
};
```

### 2) If A is compiled with a reference type (for example `int&`):

Then I need A to look like this:

```
class A{
private:
    T& m_member;

public:
    A(T& _member);    
    //... MORE STUFF
    void foo(T param); // still the same T, not T&
};
```

If I knew A received only ints, then i would be able to use specialization.
But any type can be used by A's user:

main.cpp

```
A<int> a1;//1st version
A<int&> a2;//2nd version
A<B> a3;//1st version
A<B&> a4;//2nd version
A<C*> a5;//1st version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen (correctly) in this thread [Specializing function template for reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677592/specializing-function-template-for-reference-types), the remove_reference suggested here won't work. It just won't go into the second implementation EVER, because the compiler sees T& and T just the same.

Instead you could MANUALLY tell the compiler that it is now dealing with a reference type, using the same specialization trick

```
template<typename T, bool isReference>
class A {
};

template<typename T>
class A<T,false>{
private:
    T m_member;

public:
    A(T _member);    
    //... MORE STUFF
    void foo(T param);
}
/////////////////////////
template<typename T>
class A<T,true>{
private:
    T& m_member;

public:
    A(T& _member);    
    //... MORE STUFF
    void foo(T param);
}
```

If you want to extract some similar behavior and avoid the code dupelication this solution causes, you could easily extract that behavior to a Base `Class<T>`, and do

```
template<typename T,bool isReference>
class A : public BaseClass<T>{
}
```

and so on.

Usage would be

main.cpp

```
A<int,false> a1;//1st version
A<int&,true> a2;//2nd version
A<B,false> a3;//1st version
A<B&,true> a4;//2nd version
A<C*,false> a5;//1st version, as pointers are value types
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb My actual question is weather or not there is a semantic difference between `int` and `int&`? defining `void foo(int a){cout<<"int";}` and `void foo(int& a){cout<<"int&";}` in the same file compiles. calling with `f(4);` will output `"int"`, but calling with `int b; f(b)` will give ambiguity to the compiler. same goes for `int& c = b`.
If i define a template<T> and a specialization of <T&>, would two distinct classes be created? could you show working code for that? (the question I linked to shows the opposite).

Comment: Yes, `A<int>` and `A<int&>` are distinct classes. See my answer to this question for working code.

Comment: In the linked question, `f<int>` and `f<int&>` are distinct functions, but he only ever calls `f<int>`.  The code `f<int&>(z);` would call `f<int&>`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Credit for ideas in this answer goes to n.m.

To make your idea work, you just need to make the function argument type for `foo` to always be a non-reference type.  In C++11 there is a helper function template  called `std::remove_reference` for that, but in C++03 that can easily be implemented.  Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
template<typename T> struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};

template<typename T>
class A{
private:
    T m_member;

public:
    A(T m): m_member(m) {}
    void foo(typename remove_reference<T>::type param) { param = 0; }
};

struct B { int x; B(int x): x(x) {} };
struct C {};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    A<int> a1(a);
    A<int&> a2(a);

    a1.foo(a); std::cout << a << std::endl;
    a2.foo(a); std::cout << a << std::endl;

    B b(1);
    A<B> b1(b);
    A<B&> b2(b);
    b1.foo(b); std::cout << b.x << std::endl;
    b2.foo(b); std::cout << b.x << std::endl;

    C c;
    A<C*> c1(&c);
    c1.foo(&c);
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -o r r.cc -std=c++03 && ./r
1
1
1
1
```

As you can see, the `1` output indicates that the argument was passed by value (and so `param = 0` is changing a local copy, not the object given as argument).

Another way to verify that the code is working as intended would be to output the gcc extension `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` inside `foo`. The output for that line with the call `a2.foo(a);` is:

```
void A<T>::foo(typename remove_reference<T>::type) [with T = int&; typename remove_reference<T>::type = int]
```